# Agrupar Array por coincidencias

Tags: array, angular, typescript, object, data

Mi pregunta va primeramente porque estoy desarrollando un proyecto donde necesito listar los medicamentos asociados a una formula médica, pero luego de guardar los datos al momento de visualizarlos, me repite el encabezado de la formula múltiples veces, por lo cual necesito hacer una agrupación de los medicamentos que tengan un `id_formula` en común. 
Este es el Array que viene desde la base de datos:

```
let array = [
    {"id_formula":"12342341234123","fecha_formula":"2018-10-18 00:00:00","id_residente":42999857,"dosis_medicamento":2,"lapso":6,"dias":8,"nombre_medicamento":"Acetaminofen","dosis":100,"unidad_medida":"mg","nombre_aplicacion":"Sublingal"},
    {"id_formula":"12342341234123","fecha_formula":"2018-10-18 00:00:00","id_residente":42999857,"dosis_medicamento":1,"lapso":12,"dias":10,"nombre_medicamento":"Naproxeno","dosis":500,"unidad_medida":"mg","nombre_aplicacion":"Oral"},
    {"id_formula":"1234567890987","fecha_formula":"2018-10-18 00:00:00","id_residente":12345678,"dosis_medicamento":1,"lapso":5,"dias":2,"nombre_medicamento":"Clonacepan","dosis":25,"unidad_medida":"mg","nombre_aplicacion":"Oral"},
    {"id_formula":"1234567890987","fecha_formula":"2018-10-18 00:00:00","id_residente":12345678,"dosis_medicamento":3,"lapso":12,"dias":3,"nombre_medicamento":"Acetaminofen","dosis":100,"unidad_medida":"mg","nombre_aplicacion":"Sublingal"}]
```

Y necesito que quede algo tipo:

```
let array = [
    {"id_formula":"12342341234123",
     "fecha_formula":"2018-10-18 00:00:00",
     "id_residente":42999857,
     "medicamentos": [
         {"dosis_medicamento":2,
          "lapso":6,
          "dias":8,
          "nombre_medicamento": "Acetaminofem",
          "dosis": 100,
          "unidad_medida": "mg",
          "nombre_aplicacion": "Sublingual"
         },
         {"dosis_medicamento":1,
          "lapso":12,
          "dias":10,
          "nombre_medicamento": "Naproxeno",
          "dosis": 500,
          "unidad_medida": "mg",
          "nombre_aplicacion": "Oral"
         }
       ]
     },
     {"id_formula":"1234567890987",
     "fecha_formula":"2018-10-18 00:00:00",
     "id_residente":12345678,
     "medicamentos": [
         {"dosis_medicamento":1,
          "lapso":5,
          "dias":2,
          "nombre_medicamento": "Clonacepan",
          "dosis": 25,
          "unidad_medida": "mg",
          "nombre_aplicacion": "Oral"
         },
         {"dosis_medicamento":3,
          "lapso":12,
          "dias":3,
          "nombre_medicamento": "Acetaminofen",
          "dosis": 100,
          "unidad_medida": "mg",
          "nombre_aplicacion": "Sublingual"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Llevo 1 semana buscando una solución y lo único que encuentro hacer es agrupar solo uno de los medicamentos, agradecería bastante la ayuda y seria de gran aprendizaje

**Nota:**  Los datos son ficticios

Comment: ¿Qué haces con el resto de campos comunes (fecha_formula e id_residente)? ¿Estás seguro de que siempre son iguales?

Comment: Los agrupo a los encabezados de la formula, ya que son datos que son comunes entre si

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para efectuar esto has de desarrollar tu mismo la función de agrupamiento, una forma de efectuarlo sería de la siguiente manera:

- Definición de las clases para los diferentes objectos:

**clase Medicamento**

```
class Medicamento {
  dosis_medicamento: number;
  lapso: number;
  dias: number;
  nombre_medicamento: string;
  dosis: number;
  unidad_medida: string;
  nombre_aplicacion: string;
  constructor(
    dosis_medicamento,
    lapso,
    dias,
    nombre_medicamento,
    dosis,
    unidad_medida,
    nombre_aplicacion
  ) {
    this.dosis_medicamento = dosis_medicamento;
    this.lapso = lapso;
    this.dias = dias;
    this.nombre_medicamento = nombre_medicamento
    this.dosis = dosis;
    this.unidad_medida = unidad_medida;
    this.nombre_aplicacion = nombre_aplicacion;
  }
}
```

**clase Formula**

```
class Formula {
    id_formula: string; 
      fecha_formula: string;
      id_residente:number; 
      medicamentos: Medicamento[] = [];

    constructor(
      id_formula, 
      fecha_formula, 
      id_residente){
        this.id_formula = id_formula;
        this.fecha_formula = fecha_formula;
        this.id_residente = id_residente;
    }

    addMedicamento(medicamento) {
        this.medicamentos.push(medicamento);
    }
}
```

- A posterior, deberías tener una función que itere y vaya efectuando la agrupación de los medicamentos por formula:

  ```
  function groupMedicamentosByFormula() {
     let array = [
     { "id_formula": "12342341234123", "fecha_formula": "2018-10-18 00:00:00", 
     "id_residente": 42999857, "dosis_medicamento": 2, "lapso": 6, 
     "dias": 8, "nombre_medicamento": "Acetaminofen", "dosis": 100, 
     "unidad_medida": "mg", "nombre_aplicacion": "Sublingal" },
     { "id_formula": "12342341234123", "fecha_formula": "2018-10-18 00:00:00", 
     "id_residente": 42999857, "dosis_medicamento": 1, "lapso": 12, 
     "dias": 10, "nombre_medicamento": "Naproxeno", "dosis": 500, 
     "unidad_medida": "mg", "nombre_aplicacion": "Oral" },
     { "id_formula": "1234567890987", "fecha_formula": "2018-10-18 00:00:00", 
     "id_residente": 12345678, "dosis_medicamento": 1, "lapso": 5, 
     "dias": 2, "nombre_medicamento": "Clonacepan", "dosis": 25, 
     "unidad_medida": "mg", "nombre_aplicacion": "Oral" },
     { "id_formula": "1234567890987", "fecha_formula": "2018-10-18 00:00:00", 
     "id_residente": 12345678, "dosis_medicamento": 3, "lapso": 12, 
     "dias": 3, "nombre_medicamento": "Acetaminofen", "dosis": 100, 
     "unidad_medida": "mg", "nombre_aplicacion": "Sublingal" }];

      var formulas: Formula[] = [];
      var auxFormula: Formula;
      var auxFormulas: Formula[];

      // recorremos el array
      array.forEach((item) => {
         // obtenemos la formula si ya esta en el array de formulas
         auxFormulas = formulas.filter((formula) => formula.id_formula === item.id_formula);

        auxFormula = auxFormulas.length === 0 ? undefined : auxFormulas[0];
        // si no existe creamos la formula y la añadimos al array
        if (!auxFormula) {
          auxFormula = new Formula(item.id_formula, item.fecha_formula, item.id_residente);
          formulas.push(auxFormula);
        }

        // si ya existe el medicamento dentro de la formula pasamos al siguiente medicamento
        if (auxFormula.medicamentos.filter((medicamento) => medicamento.nombre_medicamento === item.nombre_medicamento).length > 0) {
          return;
        }

        // si no existe el medicamento lo añadimos en la formula
        auxFormula.addMedicamento(new Medicamento(item.dosis_medicamento, item.lapso, item.dias, item.nombre_medicamento, item.dosis, item.unidad_medida, item.nombre_aplicacion));
      });

      console.log(auxFormula);

    }
  ```

Comment: De todas maneras lo ideal sería agrupar en servidor, ya que la performance se verá afectada por el pc

Comment: Construir estas clases en base a un JSON es una tarea muy pesada e innecesaria, lo normal tratándose de Typescript y Angular es que sean interfaces.

Comment: @PabloLozano estoy de acuerdo en que se podría usar interfaces, aunque si luego quieres añadir un serializador dinámico que verifique el cumplimiento de la interface, es necesario un tipo

Comment: A lo que voy es que seguramente ese array se haya obtenido mediante una llamada AJAX, usando JSON.parse(), por lo que ningún elemento del array será de otra clase distinta a Object

Comment: @PabloLozano  Al ser por angular se habrá obtenido por httpclient el cual sus funciones (get/post...) Permite recibir un tipo genérico

Comment: Angular y HttpClient no dejan de usar un XMLHttpRequest por debajo, y al procesar un JSON usarán JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

#### Posible solución:

```
class Test {

    constructor() {
        this.filterFormulas();
    }

    private filterFormulas() {
        console.log('filterFormulas()'); // HACK: trace

        const arr = [
            {
                'id_formula': '12342341234123',
                'fecha_formula': '2018-10-18 00:00:00',
                'id_residente': 42999857,
                'dosis_medicamento': 2,
                'lapso': 6,
                'dias': 8,
                'nombre_medicamento': 'Acetaminofen',
                'dosis': 100,
                'unidad_medida': 'mg',
                'nombre_aplicacion': 'Sublingal'
            },
            {
                'id_formula': '12342341234123',
                'fecha_formula': '2018-10-18 00:00:00',
                'id_residente': 42999857,
                'dosis_medicamento': 1,
                'lapso': 12,
                'dias': 10,
                'nombre_medicamento': 'Naproxeno',
                'dosis': 500,
                'unidad_medida': 'mg',
                'nombre_aplicacion': 'Oral'
            },
            {
                'id_formula': '1234567890987',
                'fecha_formula': '2018-10-18 00:00:00',
                'id_residente': 12345678,
                'dosis_medicamento': 1,
                'lapso': 5,
                'dias': 2,
                'nombre_medicamento': 'Clonacepan',
                'dosis': 25, 'unidad_medida': 'mg',
                'nombre_aplicacion': 'Oral'
            },
            {
                'id_formula': '1234567890987',
                'fecha_formula': '2018-10-18 00:00:00',
                'id_residente': 12345678,
                'dosis_medicamento': 3,
                'lapso': 12, 'dias': 3,
                'nombre_medicamento': 'Acetaminofen',
                'dosis': 100, 'unidad_medida': 'mg',
                'nombre_aplicacion': 'Sublingal'
            }
        ];

        const response = this.filterByFormulaId(arr);
        console.log('Filtered formulas:'); // HACK: trace of results
        console.log(response);
    }

    private filterByFormulaId(arr: any): any {
        console.log('filterByFormulaId()'); // HACK: trace

        const response = [];
        const arrLength = arr.length;
        console.log('Elements to filter: ' + arrLength); // HACK: trace

        for (let i = 0; i < arrLength; i ++) {
            const formula = arr[i];
            // console.log('Show formula ' + i);  // HACK: traces
            // console.log(formula);

            if (! this.isInArrayOfFormulas(formula, response)) {
                response.push(formula);
            }
        }

        return response;
    }

    private isInArrayOfFormulas(formula: any, response: any): boolean {
        console.log('isInArrayOfFormulas()'); // HACK: trace

        const arrLength = response.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
            console.log('To analize - ID: ' + formula.id_formula); // HACK: trace

            // Check each element by 'id_formula'
            if (response[i].id_formula === formula.id_formula) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

new Test();
```

#### Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Explicación

Se recorre cada elemento del array, es decir cada fórmula, para ir comparando si se repiten la propiedad `id_formula`, para esto se usa `isInArrayOfFormulas()` que devuelve un booleano según si encuentra o no esa id, recibiendo la formula actual (de cada iteración) y un array donde se van guardando las formulas (excluyendo las repeticiones, según 'id_formula').

He dejado algunas trazas, puedes ver que aunque se analizan cuatro elementos, solo se esta comparando una ID tres veces, eso es porque el primer elemento del array original entra directamente al array resultante, es decir que no se va a iterar el array resultante en `isInArrayOfFormulas()` cuando este esta vacío.

#### Nota

Me he ceñido a resolver tu problema, ***filtrar los elementos para que no se repitan según la propiedad 'id_formula'***. Ya no se si tus datos o lógica para obtenerlos son correctos. Me he fijado que en dos elementos con la misma 'id_formula' hay datos que difieren, como la dosis o el nombre de medicamento, al hacer el filtrado solo tendrás los datos los datos del primer elemento, perderás los del resto de elementos con la id repetida.

Saludos.